# How to keep the last selected file from sg.filebrowser in default_text from sg.InputText?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

First of all, PySimpleGUI is magnificent!!

How to save the last selected file in sg.filebrowser so that the next time I run the script, this file will be the default value in default_text from sg.InputText?

Today I have this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  
            [sg.Text('Selecione o Arquivo Executável na Pasta de Instalação               '), sg.InputText(default_text='' key='EXE_SPED'), sg.FileBrowse(button_text='Selecione')],
            [sg.Text('Selecione a Pasta Com os Arquivos .REC e .TXT                                '), sg.InputText(key='PASTA_ARQUI'), sg.FolderBrowse(button_text='Selecione')],
            [                                   sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('CANCELAR')]]

Window = sg.Window('Print Folder  --  Versão 1.0', layout=layout)

while True:
    event, values = Window.read()

    if event in (None, 'CANCELAR'): # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if event == 'OK':
       print(Pvalues['EXE_SPED'])
```

Imagine that I selected the file C: \ Users \ Felipe \ Downloads \ Output.txt, clicked ok, the program was executed and then closed the window. So I opened the program again and will it be like this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  
            [sg.Text('Selecione o Arquivo Executável na Pasta de Instalação               '), sg.InputText(default_text='C: \ Users \ Felipe \ Downloads \ Output.txt' key='EXE_SPED'), sg.FileBrowse(button_text='Selecione')],
            [sg.Text('Selecione a Pasta Com os Arquivos .REC e .TXT                                '), sg.InputText(key='PASTA_ARQUI'), sg.FolderBrowse(button_text='Selecione')],
            [                                   sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('CANCELAR')]]

Window = sg.Window('Print Folder  --  Versão 1.0', layout=layout)

while True:
    event, values = Window.read()

    if event in (None, 'CANCELAR'): # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if event == 'OK':
       print(values['EXE_SPED'])
```

Is there a way to do this without having to save the value in another file (like a txt for example)?

Comment: No, from my opinion you can not get variable value after closing the window.
you have to store selected path to the any txt file.

Comment: I thought maybe it could because the sg.folderbrowse method, when the window closes and I open a new program goes directly to the last folder I selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the previously selected file paths with PySimpleGUI settings. The settings are saved in a file (you can show its location with `print(f'Your settings file {sg.user_settings_filename()}')`). See also [User Settings example](https://altsimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=user_settings_get_entry#example-user-settings-usage)

Here's a demo (with code from https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_User_Settings_Browse_File_Folder.py):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Name:", size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text("File path:", size=(10, 1)), sg.Combo(sg.user_settings_get_entry('-filenames-', []), default_value=sg.user_settings_get_entry('-last filename-', ''), size=(50, 1), key='-FILENAME-'),
           sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Button("Go"), sg.B("Clear"), sg.Button("Exit")]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("My App", layout)

# event loop
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Go':
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-filenames-', list(set(sg.user_settings_get_entry('-filenames-', []) + [values['-FILENAME-'], ])))
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-last filename-', values['-FILENAME-'])
            window['-FILENAME-'].update(values=list(set(sg.user_settings_get_entry('-filenames-', []))), value=sg.user_settings_get_entry('-last filename-', ''))
            # print location of settings file
            # print(f'Your settings file {sg.user_settings_filename()}')
        elif event == 'Clear':
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-filenames-', [])
            sg.user_settings_set_entry('-last filename-', '')
            window['-FILENAME-'].update(values=[], value='')
    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The newer popups have a `history` parameter that saves previously selected items and shows them to you in a combo box similar to your solution.  Set `history=True` in the "get popups" to access this feature.

Comment: @MikefromPSG that's a useful feature! I'm going to check it out